# How to access variable out of current range control in helm template

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a helm template like this,

```
1  {{- range $device_type := include "example.supportedDevices" . }}
3  {{- $total_worker_sets := get $.Values.all_worker_sets $device_type }}
4  {{- range $item := $total_worker_sets }}
5  {{- if eq $device_type "cpu" }}
6  {{- $type := "cpu" }}
7  {{- else }}
8  {{- $type := $item.name }}
9  {{- end }}
10  {{- range $i, $e := until ($item.worker_sets|int) }}
11  ---
12  apiVersion: apps/v1
13  kind: StatefulSet
14  metadata:
15    name: {{ template "example.fullname" $ }}-worker-{{ $type }}-{{ $i }}
16  spec:
...
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

and `helm lint` returns:
[ERROR] templates/: parse error at (example/templates/worker.yaml:15): undefined variable "$type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$` to get to the root scope. So instead of `.type` you can use `$.type`. Here you used `$type`, that is why it's showing undefined (`undefined variable "$type"`, rather it would be `$.type`.

Answer (score 4):

When you assigned the `$type` with `:=` inside an `if-block`, the scope is limited only to that `if-block`. Define the variable outside the `if-block` so that you can use it later.

```
1  {{- range $device_type := include "example.supportedDevices" . }}
3  {{- $total_worker_sets := get $.Values.all_worker_sets $device_type }}
x  {{- $type := "" }}   ### <----define here
4  {{- range $item := $total_worker_sets }}
5  {{- if eq $device_type "cpu" }}
6  {{- $type = "cpu" }}  ### <--- replace :=  with = to avoid re-declaration
7  {{- else }}
8  {{- $type = $item.name }} ### <--- replace :=  with =
9  {{- end }}
10  {{- range $i, $e := until ($item.worker_sets|int) }}
11  ---
12  apiVersion: apps/v1
13  kind: StatefulSet
14  metadata:
15    name: {{ template "example.fullname" $ }}-worker-{{ $type }}-{{ $i }}
16  spec:
...
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @KamolHasan notes in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67886552/10008173), if you try to define a variable inside an `{{ if }}...{{ end }}` block, the scope of the variable is that block.  Helm (and more specifically the Sprig extension template library) provides a [`ternary`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#ternary) extension function to work around this.

`ternary` takes three arguments; in order, the true-value, the false-value, and the condition.  This specific ordering lets you use template pipeline syntax to provide the condition.  It's similar in spirit to the `? :` inline-conditional operators in C-like languages

```
{{ $value := ternary "if-true" "if-false" $condition }}
```

```c
const char *value = condition ? "if-true" : "if-false";
```

That would let you promote `$type` out of the conditional block

```
{{- range $item := $total_worker_sets }}
{{- $type := eq $device_type "cpu" | ternary "cpu" $item.name }}
{{- range $i, $e := until ($item.worker_sets|int) }}
name: {{ template "example.fullname" $ }}-worker-{{ $type }}-{{ $i }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```